# What the difference between ExecutorService's execute and thread.run in running threads concurrently in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice

I'm new to this concurrent programming in java and came up with following scenarios where I'm getting confusion which to use when.

**Scenario 1:** In the following code I was trying to run threads by calling **.start()** on GPSService class which is a Runnable implementation.

```
int clientNumber = 0;
ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(port);

while (true) {
            new GPSService(listener.accept(), clientNumber++, serverUrl).start();
}
```

**Scenario 2:** In the following code I was trying to run threads by using ExecutorService class as shown

```
int clientNumber = 0;
ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(port);
while(true) {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executor.execute(new GPSService(listener.accept(), client++, serverUrl));

        executor.shutdown();
        while (!executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
            // Threads are still running
            System.out.println("Thread is still running");
        }
        // All threads are completed
        System.out.println("\nThread completed it's execution and terminated successfully\n");              
}
```

My Questions are 
Which is the best practice to invoke a thread in concurrent programming?
What will be result(troubles) I'll end up with when I use first or second? 
**Note**: I've been facing an issue with the first scenario  where the program is getting hanged after every few days. So, is that issue related/expected when I use first method.?
Any good/helpful answer will be appreciated :) Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Thread Pool vs Thread Spawning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049948/thread-pool-vs-thread-spawning)

Comment: @NarendraPathai I'm more specific to my question, if so how can you mark it as duplicate???

Comment: @NarendraPathai I've just mentioned hanging just to clarify whether FirstScenario has possibility of causing such issues. For your understanding, I didn't ask solution for that hanging issue. And thank you for your reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no big differences in the two scenario you posted, except from managing thread termination in Scenario2; you always create a new thread for each incoming request. If you want to use ThreadPool my advice is not to create one for every request but to create one for each server and reuse threads. Something like:

```
public class YourClass {

//in init method or constructor 
ExecutorService executor = Executors....;// choose from newCachedThreadPool() or newFixedThreadPool(int nThreads) or some custom option


int clientNumber = 0;
ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(port);
while(true) {

    executor.execute(new GPSService(listener.accept(), client++, serverUrl));

}
```

This will allow you to use a thread pool and to control how many threads to use for your server. If you want to use a Executor this is the preferred way to go.

With a server pool you need to decide how many threads there are in the pool; you have different choices but you can start or with a fixed number or threads or with a pool that tries to use a non busy thread and if all threads are busy it creates a new one (`newCachedThreadPool()`). The number of threads to allocate depends form many factors: the number of concurrents requests and it durations. The more your server side code takes time the more you need for additional thread. If your server side code is very faster there are very high chances that the pool can recycle threads already allocated (since the requests do not come all in the same exact instant).

Say for example that you have 10 request during a second and each request lasts 0.2 seconds; if the request arrive at 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, .. part of the second (for example 23/06/2015 7:16:00:00, 23/06/2015 7:16:00:01, 23/06/2015 7:16:00:02) you need only three threads since the request coming at 0.3 can be performed by the thread that server the first request (the one at 0), and so on (the request at time 0.4 can reuse thread used for the request that came at 0.1). Ten requests managed by three threads.

I recommend you (if you did not it already) to read *Java Concurrency in practice* (Task Execution is chapter 6); which is an excellent book on how to build concurrent application in Java.

Comment: So If I use newCachedThreadPool() or newFixedThreadPool(int nThreads), since I'm getting data for every four seconds from hundreds of clients, won't I be ending with any problems if I don't use single thread for each client?

Comment: No problems if you manage to size the pool correctly, with newCachedThreadPool() you dont'have even to put an upperbound on the thread number

Answer (score 1):

From oracle [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool--) from `Executors`

```
public static ExecutorService newCachedThreadPool()
```

> Creates a thread pool that creates new threads as needed, but will reuse previously constructed threads when they are available. These pools will typically improve the performance of programs that execute many short-lived asynchronous tasks.
>
> Calls to execute will reuse previously constructed threads if available. If no existing thread is available, a new thread will be created and added to the pool. Threads that have not been used for sixty seconds are terminated and removed from the cache.
>
> Thus, a pool that remains idle for long enough will not consume any resources. Note that pools with similar properties but different details (for example, timeout parameters) may be created using ThreadPoolExecutor constructors.

```
public static ExecutorService newFixedThreadPool(int nThreads)
```

> Creates a thread pool that reuses a fixed number of threads operating off a shared unbounded queue. At any point, at most nThreads threads will be active processing tasks. If additional tasks are submitted when all threads are active, they will wait in the queue until a thread is available.
>
> If any thread terminates due to a failure during execution prior to shutdown, a new one will take its place if needed to execute subsequent tasks. The threads in the pool will exist until it is explicitly shutdown.

**@Giovanni** is saying that you don' have to provide number of threads to `newCachedThreadPool` unlike `newFixedThreadPool`(), where you have to pass maximum cap on number of threads in ThreadPool.

But between these two, `newFixedThreadPool()` is preferred. `newCachedThread Pool` may cause leak and you may reach maximum number of available threads due to unbounded nature. Some people consider it as an evil.

Have a look at related SE question:

[Why is an ExecutorService created via newCachedThreadPool evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017963/why-is-an-executorservice-created-via-newcachedthreadpool-evil)

Comment: When using newFixedThreadPool() how can you determine what number to use for threads.

Comment: Start with Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()